On the Fundamental Theorem of the Local Theory of Curves
The Fundamental Theorem of the Local Theory of Curves is often states as the following:

The last line of the theorem states "with positive determinant". What is the significance of this and why is this condition true?

Some curves don't match its mirror reflection. With positive determinant the curve doesn't transform into its mirror reflection.

@RafaBudría so positive determinant ensures that the rigid motion will be only rotation and translation but not reflection?

The reflections entail a negative determinant.

The fundamental theorem of the local theory of curve's goal is to give a uniqueness and existence theorem of the solution of the system of differential equations defined by the Frénet equations. This goal is frustrated by the fact that, strictly speaking, the velocity, curvature and torsion of a curve are self-referencing properties that refer to how the curve relates to itself; because of that, specifying that triad can never specify the curves position and orientation in space. This means that every solution to this problem is unique, granted we mod out this ambiguity (meaning, position in space- translations, and orientation- rotations).
Now, notice that a rotation needs to leave the norms of the vectors invariant, and their orientation invariant as well. This means that if $\rho$ is a rotation, then it satisfies $\rho \rho^T=I$ and $|\rho|=1$.
Why must we exclude orthogonal (the first property) transformations of negative determinant? Because mirroring the curve will flip the sign of its velocity, hence of its normal, but not of its binormal. This means that mirror transformations change the way that velocity, curvature and torsion refer to the curve itself; this is not the kind of ambiguity that is meant to be left out, hence, it could never be an invariance of the Frénet equations. One other way of seeing this is performing mirroring explicitly in the equations.

The Frenet frame $(T,N,B)$ is suppose to be direct ; in particular if you change the orientation you change the sign of the torsion.More precisely $N$ is defined as $dT/ds=\rho.N$, and $B=T\wedge N$. If you change the orientation, you change the sign of $B$ and the sign of the torison.
